# Multiple Services in the same module in Nestjs

Tags: node.js, angular, dependency-injection, nestjs, nest

I have a `Post` module which contains a controller, an entity class and two services - PostService and PostCacheService.

```
@Module({
  controllers: [PostController],
  providers: [PostService, PostCacheService, PaginationService, Logger],
  imports: [
    MikroOrmModule.forFeature({
      entities: [Post, User, Comment],
    })
  ],
  exports: [PostService, PostCacheService],
})
export class PostModule {}
```

These are the classes I am injecting in PostService.

```
constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Post)
    private readonly postRepository: postRepository,
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private readonly userRepository: UserRepository,
    @InjectRepository(Comment)
    private readonly commentRepository: EntityRepository<Comment>,
    private readonly logger: Logger,
    private readonly postCacheService: PostCacheService,
  ) {}
```

And these are the classes I am injecting PostCacheService:

```
constructor(
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER)
    private cacheManager: Cache,
    private logger: Logger,
    private readonly postService: PostService,
  ) {}
```

I am injecting PostService in PostCacheService and injecting PostCacheService in PostService.

This is the error I am getting: `Nest can't resolve dependencies of the PostCacheService (CACHE_MANAGER, Logger, ?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [2] is available in the PostModule context.`

Any Idea how to fix this? And is it possible to use two services in a module?
Thanks.

Comment: ... well, try 'forwardRef' the serviced di-prover missing, maybe ...

Comment: Thanks, it worked. My bad didn't read docs properly.